# Website opened on Chrome by Selenium intermittently hangs opening blocks (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Python v 3.12.0
Selenium v 4.17.2
Chrome v 121.0.6167.160 (Official Build) (arm64)
Macbook Air OS v 14.2.1 (23C71)

Before I start - thanks a lot for anyone taking the time to have a look at this problem. Very much appreciated.

I'm trying to automatically book a tennis court on a scheduled basis on a site called gotcourts.com. I can log in with a python script and selenium 100% of the time. 80% of the time, once logged in, chrome hangs on two blocks which are displayed as 'loading' but never actually load. The other 20% of the time, the two blocks load pretty much immediately. If I log on manually, the two blocks always load.

I am guessing that in opening chrome with Selenium rather than clicking on the chrome icon, some chrome parameter has changed due to the different context however I have no idea how to track it down. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import yaml
    import time

    conf = yaml.safe_load(open('LoginDetails.yml'))
    UsrName = conf['User']['email']
    Pword = conf['User']['password']

    Opts=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    Opts.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    Opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])
    Opts.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Opts) 

    driver.get("https://apps.gotcourts.com/en/")
    driver.find_element("id", "username").send_keys(UsrName)
    driver.find_element("id","password").send_keys(Pword)
    RememberMeCheckBox=driver.find_element(By.ID,"rememberMe")
    if RememberMeCheckBox.is_selected():
       RememberMeCheckBox.click()

    driver.find_element("id","id-login").click()

    time.sleep(30) #allows grabbing of Chrome console messages
    driver.close()
```

Here are images of the website with the blocks hung in a loading state and when the blocks load properly
[image: Blocks hanging]

[image: Blocks loaded correctly]

Here are images of the messages in the console at Chrome/View/Developer/Developer Tools/Console. I have to admit I have no idea what these mean or even if they are helpful. Any comments on this would be appreciated too!

- console messages of a failed scripted log in
- console messages of a successful scripted log in
- console messages of a successful manual log in

**FAILED SCRIPTED LOG IN**
[image: FS1]
[image: FS2]
[image: FS3]
**SUCCESSFUL SCRIPTED LOG IN**
[image: SS]
**SUCCESSFUL MANUAL LOG IN**
[image: SM]

As I've mentioned - many thanks for any comments you can add!

Comment: Since the error in the log is a CORS error, have you tried adding the option --disable-web-security?

Comment: as @ordinary_python_programmer pointed out, it looks like the CORS error is the difference. (and that flag would turn off CORS rules so it's worth a try) I think it's trying to get back an Auth token there to use to authenticate a session.  Since it's working 20% of the time, and this site looks to have some problems even when you manually browse there, it suggests that they are just updating the site and/or trying to fix some issues.  In the fail state, is it showing that you are logged in?  (hard to tell if you blacked out the profile icon in your screenshot)  You should include login code.

Comment: one thing that might cause this (though not the CORS error, that looks like a bug on their end) is navigating directly after logging in.  The site will try to set a cookie or  local storage, but you don't give the browser enough time to do that... or for the script to read local storage to set a value in headers of fetch requests.  The random behavior suggests a timing issue there.  A simple sleep after logging in would help that.  Could also be a timing issue with their async scripts... sending refresh might help that.  Selenium could affect timing slightly.

Comment: I agree with @browsermator, putting a few time.sleep(0.1) in the code could help too and would not hurt performance notably. But first I'd try if the option already fixes the problem. Selenium being too fast can cause problems indeed. Also maybe check if you are using the same browser profile, had a few issues with that.  Not sure what else could be the difference that causes your problem.

Comment: @ordinary_python_programmer, option --disable-web-security worked a treat! Thanks for both of your comments!

(@browsermator)